# Is this correct in Rcpp?

Tags: r, rcpp

I want to compare each columns, and return all the results after calculating. I try to write the codes, but the outcome was not resonable. Because if there are 5 columns in a matrix, the number of result will will be 5*4/2=10 rather than 5. I think the problem is the `m` in codes. I don't know whether it is correct. Thanks.

```
library(Rcpp)
sourceCpp(code='
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h> 

double KS(arma::colvec x, arma::colvec y) {
  int n = x.n_rows;
  arma::colvec w = join_cols(x, y);
  arma::uvec z = arma::sort_index(w);
  w.fill(-1); w.elem( find(z <= n-1) ).ones();
  return max(abs(cumsum(w)))/n;
}
// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector K_S(arma::mat mt) {
  int n = mt.n_cols;
  int m = 1;
  Rcpp::NumericVector results(n);
  for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++) {
    for (int j = i+1; j < n; j++){
      arma::colvec x=mt.col(i);
      arma::colvec y=mt.col(j);
      results[m] = KS(x, y);
      m ++;
    }
  }
  return results;
}
')

set.seed(1)
mt <- matrix(rnorm(400*5), ncol=5)
result <- K_S(t(mt))
```

```
> result
[1] 0.0000 0.1050 0.0675 0.0475 0.0650
```

Comment: There are more than `n` loops with this code.

Comment: "the outcome was not resonable".  Please be more specific.  In what way was it not reasonable?  Did you get an error?  If so, what was it?  What output did you expect given your test input?  [And, if you're using random test data, please provide a seed for reproducibility.]

Comment: Sorry, i update my question.@Limey

Comment: You declare a vector results of size `n`. However you say yourself that this vector should be of size `n*(n-1)/2`.

Comment: Your problem appears to the permutation. You can work that out without requiring the K_S part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had a couple of small errors. In fixing it, an intermediate version I had just filled a similar n by n matrix -- that made indexing errors obvious.  Returning an `arma::rowvec` also helps with possible out-of-bounds index errors (it errors by default) but lastly you (in this case !!) can actually just grow a `std::vector` instead.

#### Code

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

double KS(arma::colvec x, arma::colvec y) {
  int n = x.n_rows;
  arma::colvec w = join_cols(x, y);
  arma::uvec z = arma::sort_index(w);
  w.fill(-1); w.elem( find(z <= n-1) ).ones();
  return max(abs(cumsum(w)))/n;
}
// [[Rcpp::export]]
std::vector<double> K_S(arma::mat mt) {
  int n = mt.n_cols;
  std::vector<double> res;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = i+1; j < n; j++){
      arma::colvec x=mt.col(i);
      arma::colvec y=mt.col(j);
      res.push_back(KS(x, y));
    }
  }
  return res;
}

/*** R
set.seed(1)
mt <- matrix(rnorm(400*5), ncol=5)
result <- K_S(mt)
result
*/
```

#### Output

```
> Rcpp::sourceCpp("~/git/stackoverflow/73916783/answer.cpp")
> set.seed(1)
> mt <- matrix(rnorm(400*5), ncol=5)
> result <- K_S(mt)
> result
 [1] 0.1050 0.0675 0.0475 0.0650 0.0500 0.0775 0.0575 0.0500 0.0475 0.0600
>
```

Comment: Pleasure. Feel free to upvote (click on the upward triangle) and accept (click on the tick mark only you as original poster of the question see) if you feel that way -- and that is exactly how StackOverflow distributes "karma".

Comment: I'm really sorry. I would love to upvote, but unfortunately I did not have enough reputation. It shows that my feedback has been recorded, I hope it can work :)

Comment: I think you can accept though, and the act of accepting get you points too (five if I recall correctly).

Comment: OK, I accept your answer (though I still not meet the 15 repution, hope helpful to you).